# When comparing pictures, SIFT and ORB methods in OPenCV don't work when one picture has been mirrored

Tags: opencv, sift, orb

I'm trying to find all pictures that are "almost" identical in a folder.
By "almost identical", I mean for example you have an original picture, and you have modifications of this picture.
The modifications can be change of resolution, picture changed to greyscale, picture was cropped, picture rotated, a frame or some text was added, picture was mirrored...

I'm using OpenCV with SIFT and ORB (I choose each what method I want to use, I don't use them at the same time).
For all the picture variations, both SIFT and ORB work quite well. But not for the mirror picture.
Even if I only make a mirror image of the first picture (meaning I don't change anything else), the score is about 10%.

I don't understand, as I thought that SIFT and ORB were calculating distances of keypoints.  But when taking a mirror image, the distances don't change. Only the direction.

What am I missing ?

Here is the extract from my code :

```
if method   == 'ORB':
    finder = cv2.ORB_create()
elif method == 'SIFT':
    finder = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

lowe_ration = 0.86

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT or ORB
for i in range(0,count-1):
    for j in range(i+1,count):
        kp1, des1 = finder.detectAndCompute(all_new_images_to_compare[i],None)
        kp2, des2 = finder.detectAndCompute(all_new_images_to_compare[j],None)
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
        matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)        
        good_points = []
        for m,n in matches:
            if m.distance < lowe_ratio * n.distance:
       good_points.append(m)
       number_keypoints = 0
       if len(kp1) >= len(kp2):
           number_keypoints = len(kp1)
       else:
           number_keypoints = len(kp2)
       percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / (number_keypoints) * 100
       
        if  (percentage_similarity)>=10:
            myfile1=open("C:/Users/ABC/Documents/Find-Similar-Pictures/results_" + method + ".txt","a")
            myfile1.write(str(titles[i]) + "\t" + str(titles[j]) + "\t" + method + " (" + str(lowe_ratio) + ") \t" + str(int(percentage_similarity) ) + "\t\n")
            myfile1.close()
            print(titles[i], titles[j],"== Similarity: " + str(int(percentage_similarity)), method + " (" + str(lowe_ratio) + ")")
    print("___done with file", titles[i])
print("=====done=====")
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

You've discovered a property of ORB descriptor and SIFT's detector - neither is invariant to reflection.

If you're interested in matching reflected images, you'll need to do one of the following :

1. Use a symmetric keypoint detector, e.g. FAST, Harris or CeNSURE and then use the SIFT descriptor on the reflected keypoint.
2. implement a reflection invariant descriptor like [MBR-SIFT](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0178090).

There's a good analysis of the problem given in this paper: [Symmetric Stability of Low Level Feature Detectors](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/77041025.pdf)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Is it common to have computer vision research articles in PLOS ONE?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
This is strange that they (SIFT and ORB) don't take the mirroring into account.

Comment: Just checked, and it seems that MBR-SIFT is not available in OpenCV...

Comment: @Catree No, I wouldn't say so! I must admit I've no experience with that particular descriptor, it was just the first example I came across.

Comment: @Origami My post is incorrect - I will edit to update. SIFT descriptor is fine, it's the detector that's the issue.

Comment: @DoMakeSayThink : Hum, OK. and how can I change the detector ?  I even don't know what is a detector...
But if the SIFT descriptor is fine, then I guess it's a good news for me

Comment: @Origami I think StackOverflow discourages extended discussion in comments. Why don't you post a new question asking how to use a FAST detector with SIFT descriptor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226290/discussion-between-domakesaythink-and-origami).